# Remove undefined behavior from overflow of signed integers in constant expressions?

Tags: c++, c++20, undefined-behavior, constexpr, integer-overflow

EDIT In the actual example, it appears possible that negative overflow can happen, I've also added an example to demonstrate the error there

I'm using C++20 and trying to convert a library which relies on signed integer overflow in Java and C# into C++ code.  I'm also trying to generate the tables it uses at compile time, and allow those to be available at compile time.

In my code I get errors in reference to code that looks like this (Minimal example to reproduce the error, the solution to this will solve my problem as well):

```
#include <iostream> 

constexpr auto foo(){
    std::int64_t a = 2; 
    std::int64_t very_large_constant = 0x598CD327003817B5L; 
    std::int64_t x = a * very_large_constant; 
    return x; 
}
 
int main(){
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/TvM45vd8d

Negative overflow version

```
#include <iostream> 

constexpr auto foo(){
    std::int64_t a = -2; 
    std::int64_t very_large_constant = 0x598CD327003817B5L; 
    std::int64_t x = a * very_large_constant; 
    return x; 
}
 
int main(){
    std::cout << foo() << std::endl; 
    return 0; 
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/7zoE9r18E

I get 12905529061151879018 is out side of range representable by long long and -12905529061151879018 respectively.

I understand that undefined behavior here is not allowed, I also recognize that GCC and MSVC do not error here, and you can put a flag to make clang compile this anyway.  But what am I supposed to do to *actually* solve this issue with out switching compilers or applying the flag to ignore invalid constexpr?

Is there some way I can define the behavior I expect and want to happen here?

Comment: You can use a larger than necessary type and handle the “overflow” however you want. But no, you can’t define undefined behavior, I.e, change the way the compilers handle overflow without actually modifying the compilers, which is also a possibility since they are open source.

Comment: Assignment with overflow is not UB.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Signed integers have two's complement layout in any implementation that you could name.  It's also guaranteed to use two'
s complement layout since C++20.

This means that you can perform your math on `unsigned` integers and get well-defined overflow behavior that matches what you want your `signed` integers to do.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <bit>

constexpr auto foo(){
    std::uint64_t a = 2; 
    std::uint64_t very_large_constant = 0x598CD327003817B5L; 
    std::uint64_t x = a * very_large_constant; 
    return static_cast<std::int64_t>(x); 
}
```

Comment: Why would you need to `bit_cast`?  C++20 promises that converting to a signer integer wraps around, so a simple `static_cast<std::int64_t>` ought to suffice.

Comment: Or change the return type of `foo` to `std::int64_t` and then a simple `return x;` works.  Though you may get a warning from some compilers, which the `static_cast` would silence.

Comment: Yes, `static_cast<std::int64_t>(x)` is guaranteed to have the same bitwise conversion behavior.  I chose `std::bit_cast` only to (hopefully) better convey what is happening.

Comment: Okay, YMMV I guess.  To me it seems simpler to reason about the arithmetical properties of conversion, instead of about how they are internally represented using bits.  It is true that C++20 guarantees both, but I think of them as separate.

Comment: Also, remembering the rule as "signed integers are two's complement" can be misleading, because it may make you think that signed integer overflow (e.g. `a+b`) will behave in a two's-complement wrapping fashion, which is false; it remains UB even in C++20.

Comment: I changed the cast to `static_cast` to avoid any confusion.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot do this with signed integers. *However*, there are some things you can rely on in C++20:

1. Unsigned integer overflow is well-defined.
2. Signed integers are *required* to be represented as 2's complement.
3. Conversions between corresponding sized and unsigned integers preserve the bitpattern.

So you can do all of your overflow-based math using explicitly unsigned types and literals, then cast them to signed values when you need to. This conversion is required to leave the bits unchanged.

Comment: won't this fail if the values are negatively overflowing (ie I have a -2 here instead?) with out some special considerations?

Comment: As I also commented on Drew's answer, `static_cast` should work in place of `bit_cast`, unless I am really missing something.  C++20 promises that conversion to signed integer behaves in "two's complement" fashion arithmetically, independently of how it is actually represented as bits.

Comment: @Krupip: No, `std::uint64_t a = -2;` will work fine, despite looking odd.  It will assign `0xfffffffffffffffe` to `a`, which plays exactly the role of `-2` for purposes of addition, subtraction and multiplication.

Comment: @NateEldredge: I wasn't sure about that, so I picked the answer I knew best.